# Facebook application redirection from canvas

Tags: facebook

What is the easiest way to have your facebook application redirect to a website. Currently the app loads on a canvas (iframe), I desire it to simply redirect to an external website.

An example of the functionality I am looking for is http://apps.facebook.com/the-real-hotlist/?ref=ts

or just search for the 'hotlist' facebook application... any ideas on how this is done? I have played with post-redirect url and such, no luck. Any help is appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use something like:

```
<script>top.location.href="http://google.com"</script>
```

---

**UPDATE:**
Please note that your app should not only be a redirection to an external website as per the [platform policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#features):

> The primary purpose of your Canvas or Page Tab app on Facebook must
>   not be to simply redirect users out of the Facebook experience and
>   onto an external site.

Comment: guessing this goes inside the source file that would normally appear in the canvas?

Comment: Doesn't work for me, nothing happens on the canvas page.  Is Facebook blocking this now?

Comment: No it's not blocked. And without viewing the code I can't tell whats' "not" working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a Facebook app solely for the purpose of redirecting to your site is against Facebook policies.